# Как обновить router-view при переходе страницы в Vue3?

Tags: vue-router, vue3

начал изучать Vue3. Столкнулся с проблемой пагинации. При нажатий на кнопки страниц, ни чего не происходит.  Хотелось бы чтоб при нажатий выбора страницы и потом при выборе пункта меню (которое будет с права).
 перезагружалась и выводила новые данные.

```
<template>
    <HeiderPortfoli :img='"/../public/macbook.jpg"' :title='"Портфолио"' contents="текст" :arts="0" />
    <section class="portfolio_section bg0 bg1 ">
        <div class="portfolio_page">
            <div class="portfolio_items">
                <router-view />
                <template v-for="item  in  portfolio.post " :key="item.ID">
                    <CardPortfolio :url="item.post_name" :img="item.img" :title="item.post_title"
                        :content="item.post_content" :color="item.color" />
                </template>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio_seadbar">
меню
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-if="portfolio.max_num_pages != 0 || portfolio.max_num_pages != null">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <template v-for="n in portfolio.max_num_pages" :key="n">
                    <template v-if="n == portfolio.page">
                        <span class="active">{{ n }}</span>
                    </template>
                    <template v-else>
                        <router-link :to="{ name: 'portfolio', params: { page: n } }">{{ n }}</router-link>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
<script>
function pereborpage(no) {
    var hop = 0;
    if (no == 0) {
        hop = 1;
    } else {
        hop = no;
    }
    return hop;
}
import HeiderPortfoli from '@/components/HeiderPortfoli.vue';
import CardPortfolio from '@/components/CardPortfolio.vue';
export default {
    name: 'ServicesV',
    components: {
        HeiderPortfoli,
        CardPortfolio
    },
    data() {
        return {
            portfolio: [],
            my: [],
            cms: [],
            n: 0,
            page: 1,
        };
    },
    async mounted() {

        const lrt = this.$route.params.page;
        const ThisPage = pereborpage(lrt);
        console.log(this.$route);
        console.log(lrt);
        console.log(ThisPage);
        this.page = ThisPage;
        const portfolioj = await fetch(`API?page=${this.page}`);
    }
}
</script>
```